# Can the <transition> element be used to animate individual page elements in a nuxtjs application?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Can someone tell me if the `transition` element can be used on page elements for animations in nuxt? I have seen the doc regarding page transitions, but I want to animate a number of different page elements. What I have so far does not appear to be working.

In a simple Header component, I have this:

```
<template>    
<transition name="menu-popover">
    <ul class="MenuPopover">
        <li>Payments</li>
        <li>Subscriptions</li>
        <li>Connect</li>
    </ul>
</transition>
```

And in the style tag of that component:

```
<style scoped>
.menu-popover-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(50deg);
}

.menu-popover-enter-to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.menu-popover-enter-active {
    transition: opacity, transform 200ms ease-out;
}
```

Comment: the [Nuxt Guide: Page Transition](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#transitions) already introduced well how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Look into the [Nuxt Guide: Page Transition](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#transitions), it introduces how to implement the transition for each page (or specific pages [Nuxt API: Page Transition](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-transition)) step by step very well.

**Solution 2** (**not recommend**, but if really prefer to uses `<nuxt />` inside one `<transition>` manually):

**Steps:**

1. put `<nuxt>` inside `<transition>`, like `<transition name="test"><nuxt v-show="pageShow"/></transition>`
2. add css class for transition effects,

css will be like:

```
.test-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(50deg);
}

.test-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(100deg);
}

.test-enter-active,.test-leave-active {
    transition: all 2s ease-out;
}
```

3. add one handler for router navigator (or like button click event which will trigger route change).

The handler will be like below:

```
changePage: function (newUrl) {
  this.pageShow = false //hide current page to trigger the transtion for `leave` current page
  setTimeout(()=> {
    this.pageShow = true //show new page, it will trigger the transition for `enter` new page
    this.$router.replace(newUrl) //with new url
  }, 2000) // delay 2s (after the transition of previous page finishes)
}
```